# magento SOAP API

Tags: magento, soap

How do i get the cart details of an existing user using Magento SOAP API.

I have an e-commerce Application based on Magento. There is already a desktop webpage for this e-commerce application. My  use case is this -

-> User logs in from desktop webpage and then adds an item to the cart
-> User now logs in with the same credential from mobile

I want to be able to show the item that is being added from desktop page. But right now i don't see any SOAP API which helps me query any existing cart info for an user.

Note : I am trying this from an Android Application. So please suggest anything that i can with the SOAP API's

Answer (score 0):

you can get cart information using `magento api`. using SOAP V1 you can get cart info like that

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');

// If somestuff requires api authentification,
// then get a session token
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$result = $client->call($session, 'cart.info', $quoteid);
var_dump ($result);
```

OR you can use SOAP V2. Just check this out for whole information.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.info.html